# How to convert NSImage to CIImage?

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage, ciimage

I would like to convert an NSImage to a CIImage in Swift 2.2 for a macOS app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile: "...")!
let imageData = image.tiffRepresentation!

let ciImage = CIImage(data: imageData)
```

Comment: I'ts now: .tiffRepresentation